# Leverage browser caching | modifying .htaccess file | - not working for jpg&png files

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to modify my .htaccess file by specifying an expiration for resources. When running GTMetrix it still recommends that the jpg &png images need expiration. I have tried "ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"  but to no avail.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
# Leverage Browser Caching
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: And you're sure that these images are stored locally and not externally?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to enable mod_expires module :
e2enmod mod_expires

Then you should check your syntax to be :
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"

And lastly you need to open tour site with a browser e.g. firefox and open up the web-console [Tools --> Web Developer --> Web Console], on the network tab and see the "Expires" tag in the response headers.
If it exists it is setup correctly.
If it is not, you may have some global apache configuration conflicting with your .htaccess file.